# How to access the value of string by the inheritance?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

```
import java.util.*;

class Pilot
{
   protected String PILOT = "BSIT-1A";
   public static void Subject()
   {
      String[] subs = {"Comprog11","WebDev","Digilog12","ComProg12"};
   }
   public static void Teacher()
   {
     String[] teach = {"Ms.a","Ms.b","Ms.c","Ms.d"};
   }
}
class Pilot1 extends Pilot
{
   protected String PILOT1 = "BSIT-1B";
      public static void main(String[]args)
      { 
         Pilot1 obj = new Pilot1();

        System.out.println(obj.PILOT);
        System.out.println(obj.PILOT1);
        obj.Subject();
        obj.Teacher();
      }
```

how to display the values of **Subject() and Teacher()** if I put inside it a String?It doesnt have any compiler issues but when I ran it display only the

**BSIT-1A**

**BSIT-1B**

my expected output is

```
BSIT-1A
BSIT-1B
Comprog11
Webdev
Digilog12
Comprog12
Ms.a
Ms.b
Ms.c
Ms.d
```

Comment: Things that are `static` aren't used in inheritance.

Comment: subs and teach are static so inheritance is not relevant and neither method has any print function implemented so they will not generate any output. There is really nothing in your code that makes any real use of inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the array

```
 public String[] subject() {
  return {"Comprog11","WebDev","Digilog12","ComProg12"};
 }
```

Then remove the inheritance. You don't need it for the main method. Make the pilot constants public or pass those strings into a class constructor and add a private field with a getter method, for example

```
    Pilot a = new Pilot("BSIT-1A");
    Pilot b = new Pilot("BSIT-1B");
    System.out.println(a.getCode());
    System.out.println(b.getCode());
    Arrays.stream(a.subject()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the either print the values in `Subject()` and `Teacher()` or make them return the values. Also calling `static` methods via objects is not a 
good practice. They should be invoked by the class, like `Pilot1.Subject()`.

```
class Pilot
{
    protected String PILOT = "BSIT-1A";
    public static void Subject()
    {
        String[] subs = {"Comprog11","WebDev","Digilog12","ComProg12"};
        for(String sub : subs){
            System.out.println(sub);
        }
    }
    public static void Teacher()
    {
        String[] teach = {"Ms.a","Ms.b","Ms.c","Ms.d"};
        for(String t : teach){
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I need to print it first in the void?

Comment: That will get you your desired output. Though it's not the best way to do things. Replacing your `Pilot` class with that in my answer should work, yes.